# JS Regex: `.*` and following optional groups

Tags: javascript, regex

In my string, the `/` followed by a space, and the part after is optional (zero or one).

```js
' A 123/ 1,2,3 '.match(/(?:(\/)\s+(.*)?)?\s*$/);
```

This first regex is working well. I'm getting the optional `/` and the optional content that follow the optional `/`.

But now I'm trying to also get the part before the optional `/`. However the `(.*)` is returning everything in the first group, including content that should be in next groups.

```js
' A 123/ 1,2,3 '.match(/^\s*(.*)(?:(\/)\s+(.*)?)?\s*$/);
```

How I can solve this issue to retrieve content before the `/` (that should be always there), and also the optional content from `/`, like in my first regex?

Comment: `^\s*(.*?)(?:(\/)\s+(.*))?\s*$`

Comment: Thank you for the help! Yes I just discovered the lazy option.